# Magento 1.6 CE product save observer, runs fine, but expected data not found

Tags: magento, save, product

Ive created an observer, that seems to be detected, and running fine.
The observer is used to add custom option data dynamically to products.

I was initially getting a MYSQL constraint violation, and after researching online, i think this was due to the observer trying to add custom option data to the database, BEFORE the new product i was creating, was actually saved to the database.

I changed my config.xml, so that 'catalog_product_save_before', is now 'catalog_product_save_after'.
The product saves fine, but the custom option data specified in my observer is not in the product details.

My config.xml:

```
<events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <micoavp>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Bsm_Micoavp_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>Add_CustomOptions_Automatically</method>
                    </micoavp>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
</events>
```

My observer code:

```
public function Add_CustomOptions_Automatically($observer) {


       $event = $observer->getEvent();
       $product = $event->getProduct();


   $optionData = array(
                      'is_delete'         => 0,
                      'is_require'        => false,
                      'previous_group'    => '',
                      'title'             => 'want to preorder ? ',
                      'type'              => 'checkbox',
                      'price_type'        => 'fixed',
                      'price'             => '20.0000',
                      'sort_order'        => 0,
                      'values'            => array(
                                                    array(
                                                    'is_delete'     => 0,
                                                    'title'         => 'preorder',
                                                    'price_type'    => 'percent',
                                                    'price'         => -20,
                                                    'sku'           => 'product sku',
                                                    'option_type_id'=> -1,
                                                    ))

                 );
   $product->setHasOptions(1);

  $opt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option');
   $opt->setProduct($product);
   $opt->addOption($optionData);
   $opt->saveOptions();      

          Mage::log("option should be added now");

 }
```

I got the code from this url, which states it is for 1.5 CE:
    http://www.webmasterbulletin.net/2011/04/magento-programmatically-add-custom-options/1417

Does anyone know if there is a 1.6 related tweak needed to get this to work correctly?
The custom option data specified is just a test at this stage, once i can get it to work, i will be changing the option data to be added.

many thanks

Comment: I updated the code, to include mage:log entries...and also to check if the options im trying to add are already available.

Seems, that when i update a config product, the attributes are added, if they are not available. If they are, they are not added.

When i add a new simple/config product, the attributes are not added (but the mage:log says it added the options, so must be a product assignment issue).

When i run this method...has the PRODUCT already been saved at this point? Maybe i have to save the product first?

Comment: Stranger still!
Added more data to the mage log entries. It seems it IS adding the options to the correct products, i added the product id to the logs.
When i resave those products, it says the options ARE NOT available...and so adds them again. But no custom option data is showing.

Why does it add them correctly to an existing product on update....but not to a new product on save OR update?

Comment: anyone?   should this work ok??? thx

Answer (score 0):

Every thing seems to be ok with the above piece of code. just need to add following line at the end.

```
 $product->addOption($opt);
```